# i want to know how to navigate from one XML page to another in Java AWT on button click

Tags: java, android

i am making an andriod application in which i need to go from one page to another on a button click. i have tried several things but nothing worked out.

Comment: can you explain with more details what you wanna do and what is the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so given these are different .java files, and each has it own Activity (so, different Activities) what you want to do is call an intent as such:

```
Intent myActivity = new Intent(class1.this,class2.class);
main.this.startActivity(myActivity);
```

If its in the same Activity, (which I dont recomend) just call setContentView() again